# Why scene view is fine resolution but Game view low resolution in pixels

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm testing with Ca Racing include in Unity Standard Asset and realize that somehow my Scene View look better than Game View Low resolution. I try to build the game but it look the same at the Game View at highest quality. Can anyone help me please .

PS: sorry for my bad English

Screen shot's of my project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGBDy.jpg*)

Answer (score 0):

Change scale factor to 0 in game scene which is set 1.3x

Comment: It's Zoom only bro plz briefly explain